# Renaming a file to current date and time Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, batch-file, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch on a project I'm currently working on and I'm able to successfully move the file into a new file but I'm struggling to rename this file as well. Here's my configuration:

```
    <j:step id="moveProcessedFile">
        <j:tasklet ref="processedFileMove" allow-start-if-complete="true" />
    </j:step>

<bean id="processedFileMove" class="com.ussco.wms.batch.wmcstint.MoveFileTasklet">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <bean class="JdkFileHandler" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="moveFile" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>${ipfile}</value>
            <value>${ipfile.folder}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the MoveFileTasklet. It's pretty much the same as MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter:

```
public class MoveFileTasklet extends AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator<Object> implements Tasklet{

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MoveFileTasklet.class);

    //Create method for date and time rename within Tasklet. Implement execute as well

    public boolean renameFile(File fileName){
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
        log.info("test");
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Following methods directly copied from MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter
     */
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        contribution.setExitStatus(mapResult(invokeDelegateMethod()));
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    protected ExitStatus mapResult(Object result) {
        if (result instanceof ExitStatus) {
            return (ExitStatus) result;
        }
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

}
```

where JdkFileHandler has the method `moveFile`:

```
public boolean moveFile(File fileToMove, String targetDirectory) throws IOException {
    return renameFile(fileToMove, new File(targetDirectory + FILE_SEPARATOR + fileToMove.getName()));
}
```

and renameFile:

```
private boolean renameFile(File fileToRename, File renamedTargetFile) throws IOException {
    if (!fileToRename.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(fileToRename + " does not exist.");
    } else if (!fileToRename.isFile()) {
        throw new IOException(fileToRename + " is not a file and cannot be remaned.");
    } else if (renamedTargetFile.exists()) {
        throw new IOException(renamedTargetFile + " already exists so the file " + fileToRename
                        + " cannot be renamed to it.");
    }
    return fileToRename.renameTo(renamedTargetFile);
}
```

Right now I am able to move my file to the correct location but I need to be renaming the file to `fileNamemmddyyhhmmss` Also, I am unable to change any of the methods within JdkFileHandler. I'd like to either implement my own method within the `MoveFileTasklet` that I've specified, or another way.

I know this information is all over the place. I'm not looking for the code on how to do it, just how I should proceed. Kind of stuck right now. Any advice?

Comment: So what you need is some method to append the current time to the filename? Is it not working?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do currently. I'm just unsure how to proceed. Should that be the proper placement of the renameFile method (within the MoveFileTasklet)?

Comment: You can change the method that appends the time to return a String with the current time. You're always returning false on `renameFile()`

Comment: I do what you're wanting to do on a project that i have but i don't use Spring in it. So you would need to adapt them, if needed.

Comment: That rename method is a filler. I know it returns false and that it doesn't really do anything. Not the implementation I want to include. and thank you!

Comment: Have you seen the answer i posted? Does that work for you?

Comment: It should, yes. You can take it down if you like.

Comment: Did the solution work? @MikeHenke

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't figure it out. I want to take a step back because my wiring isn't correct. I don't want to attempt to rename until I can even access the rename method. So right now I'm trying to get my logger to show me that I'm within the method, which I can't do.

Comment: Your code looks good on renaming the actual file though. That should work.

Comment: I created a new question as well, if you want to take a look. It might be a little less convoluted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119031/discussion-between-mike-henke-and-julian).

Comment: Sorry, i can't access chat from where i am right now.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my current implementation for moving archive and appending current time to file name.

```
public static void moveArchive(File file, String initDirectory, String destDirectory) {
    File finalArchive;
    File initialArchive = new File(initDirectory + file.getName());

    finalArchive = new File(destDirectory + file.getName() + "." + getCurrentDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

    if (!initialArchive.renameTo(finalArchive)) {
        log.error("Couldn't move the file.");
    }
}

public static String getCurrentDate(String format) {
    String dtStr = "";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date dt1 = new Date();

    dtStr = sdf.format(dt1);

    return dtStr;
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work for you please tell me so i can remove this.